# Error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" Using OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm a newbie to Machine Learning and trying to work through an error I'm getting using OneHotEncoder class. The error is: "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead". So when I think of 1D arrays it's something like: `[1,4,5,6]` and a 2D array would be `[[2,3], [3,4], [5,6]]`, but I still cannot figure out why this is failing. It's failing on this line:

```python
X[:, 0] = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 0]).toarray()
```

Here is my whole code:

```python
# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data2.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 5].values
df_X = pd.DataFrame(X)
df_y = pd.DataFrame(y)

# Replace Missing Values
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 3:5 ])
X[:, 3:5] = imputer.transform(X[:, 3:5])


# Encoding Categorical Data "Name"
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

# Transform into a Matrix
onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X[:, 0] = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 0]).toarray()

# Encoding Categorical Data "University"
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_x1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_x1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
```

I'm sure you can tell by this code that I have 2 columns that were labels. I used the Label Encoder to turn those columns into numbers. I'd like to use OneHotEncoder to take it one step further and turn these into a matrix so each row would have something like this:

```
0  1  0
1  0  1
```

The only thing that came to mind was how I encoded the labels. I did them one by one instead of doing them all at once. Not sure this is the problem.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```python
# Encoding Categorical Data "Name"
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

# Transform into a Matrix
onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X[:, 0] = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 0]).toarray()

# Encoding Categorical Data "University"
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_x1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

# Transform into a Matrix
onehotencoder2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X[:, 1] = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 1]).toarray()
```

Below you will find my whole error:

```
File "/Users/jim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 2.  1.  3.  2.  3.  5.  5.  0.  4.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Use `X[:, 0] = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[:, 0].reshape(-1,1)).toarray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in sklearn OneHotEncoder raised in 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3662. Most scikit learn estimators need a 2D array rather than a 1D array.

The standard practice is to include a multidimensional array. Since you have specified which column to consider as categorical for onehotencoding in `categorical_features = [0]`, you can rewrite the next line as the following to take whole dataset or a part of it. It will consider only the first column for categorical to dummy transformation while still have a multidimensional array to work with.

```
onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

(I hope your dataset doesn't have anymore categorical values. I'll advise you to labelencode everything first, then onehotencode.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error and after the error message there's a suggestion as followed:

```
"Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."
```

Since my data was an array, i used `X.values.reshape(-1,1)` and it works. (There was another suggestion to use `X.values.reshape` instead of `X.reshape`).

Answer (score 2):

I came across a fix by adding

```
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
```

the error appears to be gone now, but not sure if this is the right way to fix this

Answer (score 1):

At the moment that will change the categorical features, you need to add another pair of brackets:

```py
X[:, 0] = pd.DataFrame(onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X[[:, 0]]).toarray())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your data as the method expects a multidimensional array as mentioned previously. X = x.reshape(-1,1) worked for me as well.